# Error while Connecting to Progress AdminServer

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

When I am trying to query the running brokers its giving following error:

> Connecting to Progress AdminServer using rmi://localhost:20931/Chimera (8280)
>   Login denied, check username and password.
>   Unable to find broker (8281)

This issue could be because timing of operating system and java process of admin server are not in sync.
so for that I have added this `-XX:+UseGetTimeOfDay` in admin server proprties and restarted server however issue was not resolved 
and after that I added:

```
 JVMARGS="-Xmx256m -Xms128m -XX:+UseGetTimeOfDay ${JVMARGS}"
```

in `$DLC/bin/java_env` and again restarted the server but issue still persist. And in admin server logs it is auto generating the password.

Please provide solution.

Comment: What version and OS are you using? There are a couple of knowledgebase entries that might be [interesting for you to check](https://www.google.se/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHPS_en-GBSE461SE461&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:knowledgebase.progress.com+8280+8281)

Comment: How do you get from an error message about bad credentials to thinking that you have a timing problem?

Comment: I have searched in ProKb : "000020967 - Login denied, check username and password - System generated password has expired (9908)" and it is relevant to my problem

Comment: How is it relevant?  Did you upgrade to a more modern release or try using alternative credentials without success?

Comment: I am using 10.2b release.. and its not working with root user as well.

Comment: you need to verify your admin server port which is available at /dlc(102b)/properties/AdminServerPlugins.properties 102b/116 -depends on the version of progress used.